# How do i go about this error in react.js : (Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/pages/home') .. i have pasted the code below

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package.json

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import home from './src/pages/home';

<Route exact path='/' component={home} />

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
     <Router>
        
     <Route path='/welcome' element={<home/>} />
            
     </Router>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//this code returns a module not found error from the app.js file when I try to run it using react

Comment: Check the path of `home` import.

Comment: import home from './src/pages/home';  Literally means <current_directory>/src/pages/home. that would be app/src/pages/home is where this home code lives, if thats not the case, then double check the paths.